# Tricks for calculating very-high-order derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have to calculate the 1000th derivative of a certain function. What formulas / functions can I use?

Here is an example of the types of tricks I mean:

If $f(x)$ is an origin-symmetric function ($f(-x)=-f(x)$), then for every integer $k\geq 1$ $f^{(2k-1)}$ is y-axis-symmetric and $f^{(2k)}$ is origin-symmetric. In particular, $f^{(2k)}(0)=0$.

Most [Differentiation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules) are for first-order derivatives. I am looking for more rules that can help in calculation of very-high-order derivatives.

Comment: It depends on what functions you are looking at. For special functions like $f(x)=\sin(x)$ or $f(x)=\cos(x)$, $f^{(4k)}(x) = f(x)$

Comment: You can use Taylor series to extract high-order derivatives.

Comment: @user51547 can you please elaborate? I understand that if I know the full Taylor expansion of a function I can get its nth derivative, but in order to calculate the Taylor expansion I need to find the derivatives first...